# Unable to add Realm to Electron App

Tags: node.js, npm, realm, electron

Trying to add realm to an electron app, I get the following error.

```
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/realm/lib/browser/index.js
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/Users/adito/Documents/projects/lifelog/node_modules/realm/lib/browser'
```

I don't know why realm needs `react-native` as according to the documentation it can be installed on Node. Anyway, am I missing something on being able to install realm for electron. I installed using `npm install realm --save`.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/928 although someone seems to have been able to put it together before

Comment: Are you using the VS Code Debugger by any change?